# Test via Rest Assured returns 404 instead of 200

Tags: rest-assured

While validating a call using `Postman` and `WireShark` I can see a success response with status code `200` but when I try using `Rest Assured` I am getting a `404` error code

Below is the error

[image]

Comment: Do not include images, Please post the details in the question elaborately. Incidentally, 404 is not found, check if the request ( primarily the URI ) is according to specification

Comment: I have attached the image, the request as expected for some parameters Ex: for param a & b its working ,but for c i am seeing the error 404. 
i am able to access to URi in Postman and if i print the response it is 200 . Please refer image.

Comment: Post console logs from `Postman`, Add a `.log().all()` after `given()` ,`then()` and paste the `Rest Assured` code and the console output. Without these it will be hard to help